# Is my question too broad to be posted?

Tags: discussion, questions

> Edit: I have added an addendum to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399788/is-it-possible-for-a-python-function-to-still-use-memory-after-being-called) that should reduce the scope of the question. Apologies to all that I have annoyed and wasted time by perhaps posting the question to soon, it wasn't my intention, and I have learned how better to do it next time.

I have a question that I'd like to ask, but I'm afraid that it may be closed as too broad. I'm wondering whether someone can check it through first and offer suggestions. Here it is:

> #### Is it possible for a Python function to still use memory after being called?
>
> If I run a function in Python 3 (`func()`) is there anything that
>   could be inside `func()` that would cause it to increase its memory
>   usage?
>
> For instance, will running
>
> ```py
> def func(): 
>     # Anything and everything in here
>
> while True:
>     func()
> ```
>
> ever cause the program run out of memory, no matter what is in
>   `func()`?
>
> If the program is continually using memory, what are some possible
>   things that could be going on in `func()` to cause it to continue
>   using memory after it has been called?

Comment: I'm no Python guy, but I'm fairly certain that is going to be too broad. It sounds like you have a specific example that you're shying away from, you should start with that example and ask why it is behaving the way it is.

Comment: I think your question is a yes/no question followed by explanation. i won't flag as too broad. anyway you shouldn't be afraid your question will get closed as too broad, if so then you just have to look for ways to re-factor you question to specific situation.

Comment: Yes, I do have a specific example, but it is very large and complex, using other libraries that I have no confidence that they are not causing memory leaks.

Comment: *Narrator voiceover* [it was](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44399788/3001761).

Comment: If it truly is just a yes/no question, it likely isn't too broad, it's just... not useful. but it's more likely that any answerer to this question will assume you actually want examples of where it would consume more memory, which would be too broad.

Comment: It's the "anything" in "is there anything that could be inside `func()`" that's the trick. You could conceivably get 10,000 answers, all equally correct.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan They're not asking for examples of things to put there. They're asking if *there exists at least one* snippet of code which will cause a memory leak. It's a yes/no answer.

Comment: I think whether it is too broad depends on the answer. If the answer is "No", then that is the whole answer (not too broad). If the answer is "Yes, in a few specific ways", then probably still not too broad. Only if the answer is "Yes, there are tons of ways" then the question is too broad.

Comment: The real answer to your solution is to get a memory profiler that can track objects in memory.  You can then observe what types are sticking around, which tells you where in your code the issue is.  Not a py guy, no recommendations.

Comment: Add a list to `func.__dict__` and append an item to it inside `func`. `func` then infinitely increases in size

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in other languages that second question of what can cause memory leaks or run away consumption, can be limited to just a few specific types of memory leaks.  I could answer that question for C# or C++ in 3-5 bullet points.  Of course I could expand that to 1000s if I started generating every permutation of a code snippet that generated a memory leak, but that'd be a silly way to answer such a question.

Comment: Why bother asking if the question is Too Broad when you're just going to ignore everyone telling you that it's Too Broad and ask the question anyway?  You knew what you needed to change to fix the question, and just blatantly ignored that information.  Not only did you waste the time of the Python community needing to close a Too Broad question, but you wasted everyone's time here trying to help you craft an appropriate question when you had no intention of listening to any of the advice given.

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @Servy, I am listening to the advice, and thinking whether its possible to improve the existing question, or just create a MCVE in a new question when I have time.

Comment: @Gloin You posted the question despite being told that the question wasn't appropriate.  You should have considered the advice and improved your question *before* posting it, rather than posting it knowing that it was inappropriate and considering fixing it later, maybe.

Comment: Why are you even asking this question here? The only thing that really matters is what the community thinks if and when you actually post the question. If you are so out of touch with the community standards that you can't judge for yourself, the only way to _really_ know if your question is too broad for the community is to post the question and see if it gets closed. Granted, it's much better to read the Help section and participate on the web site so that you learn the community standards. But barring that, only the real world can give you the real answer.

Comment: Seems like a question asked out of fear of the unknown. I'm not sure what is going to happen, so I fear bad things are going to happen. Can someone tell me what bad things might happen? Its more productive to focus on how you might know that something bad is happening rather than having some incomplete checklist of things that may or may not occur in real code. Testing and measuring, two important aspects of any software engineer's development routines. Given the popularity of Python, I'm sure there is plenty of help in that area.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the comments above, the example you're providing is not specific enough. There are lots of things you could possibly do inside a function in any language in general which would cause your program to consume more memory (and then not release it, depending on the circumstances). A couple general ideas come to mind, like if the function is creating/editing objects stored outside of its scope, if you implemented some sort of memory leak, etc. These things are not specific to Python or really any other language either, so the topic you're asking about is going to be extremely broad.

Your best bet would be to find an example of a function (*along with the code inside it*) which you know does (or conversely, doesn't) increase memory usage on each call, then post that and ask why that particular case produces the results you see instead of whatever you expected.

Comment: Not "in any language in general".  Some functional languages enforce function purity (and reserve the name *function* for those subroutines which are pure).

Comment: @BenVoigt That's a good point, and thanks for bringing it up. My personal experience with functional languages has been limited to a brief stint with Haskell in a college course, so I don't consider myself very knowledgeable on that particular topic.

Answer (score 2):

I use Python daily, but I wouldn't call myself an expert because I don't know
all of the intricate details of the CPython runtime. I think the question is
reasonable, not too broad, and can be easily answered with a couple key
points.